# NextCloud: how to upload a large file via a shared link

Tags: webdav, nextcloud

I am trying to find a way to enable large file uploads (>> 1GB) on shared upload-enabled links. Direct uploading of small files via Webdav works here, when one takes the last path of the link as http user name.

However, the file size is too large to do this within a single chunk (and our admin will not increase the maximum upload size).

I found two ways to do chunked uploads programmatically:

1. [the OwnCloud one](https://github.com/owncloud/core/wiki/spec%3A-big-file-chunking):

- use a specific file name `<path/filename>-chunking-<transferid>-<chunkcount>-<index>` for each path

2. [the NextCloud one](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/19/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/chunking.html):

- manually create a directory within the url `<server>/remote.php/dav/uploads/<userid>` (http **MKCOL** request)
- upload the chunks there with http **PUT** to that directory
- moving/concatenating the contents with **MOVE** of a special file `.file` in that directory

However, these two chunked methods don't work with shared links. So, is there any way to upload large files to a NextCloud server via shared links?

I want to do this on the shell, i.e. with curl or Python or so.